# in R how can I color the labels from my phylogenetic tree? (using BioNj from ape)

Tags: r, heatmap

So I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
Pos sample_1 sample_2 celltypeX_sample3 celltypeY_sample4 celltypeX_sample5
0     0        0              3                  0             1
2     2        1              3                  0             0
5     0        0              0                  0             1
6     1        0              0                  1             0
12    0        1              0                  1             1
```

from this dataset I can calculate a correlation matrix and a heatmap  in R with:

```
data = read.table(file = "fileNameX", row.names = 1, header = T, sep = "\t")
correlationData = cor(data)
heatmap(correlationData, cexRow = 0.25, cexCol = 0.25, symm = T)
```

after this I want to make a phylogenetic tree using the bionj function of the ape library

```
arbol <- bionj(correlationData)

plot(arbol1, cex = 0.25, edge.width = 0.5)
```

Here is where I get stuck, so i have read that it is possible to change te color of the labels by adding a row that indicates in which color group it should be in. So I added this column which creates the new dataset:

```
Pos sample_1 sample_2 celltypeX_sample3 celltypeY_sample4 celltypeX_sample5
0     0        0              3                  0             1
2     2        1              3                  0             0
...
7026  0        1              0                  1             1
clr   0        0              1                  2             1
```

Is there any way I could color the labels in this way?
So everything without a celltype in the name (thus named sample_x) should have the same colour and all cell types should have the same color (thus named celltypeX_sampleY)

I hope my question is clear and it is even possible to do this...

a link to the [dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jHphFNNtYthnXrp83CcMygGndgMQcn14/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify it in the plot.phylo function. bionj returns a "phylo" class, and when you call plot(arbol1, cex = 0.25, edge.width = 0.5), you are actually using plot.phylo. You can type ?plot.phylo to see the options.

I don't have your data, but below I use an example dataset to add the color label.. Hope this is what you wanted

```
library(ape)
data(woodmouse)
trw <- bionj(dist.dna(woodmouse))
# we label samples that have No120 as blue
# others orange
COLS = ifelse(grepl("No120",trw$tip.label),"blue","orange")
plot(trw,tip.color=COLS)
```

[image]

To add colours to different labels, you can try this:

```
# from https://www.r-bloggers.com/the-paul-tol-21-color-salute/
tol18rainbow=c("#771155", "#AA4488", "#CC99BB", "#114477", "#4477AA", "#77AADD", "#117777", "#44AAAA", "#77CCCC", "#777711", "#AAAA44", "#DDDD77", "#774411", "#AA7744", "#DDAA77", "#771122", "#AA4455", "#DD7788")
# I assume here, the word before the "_" tells us how to colour the label
TYPE = gsub("_[^ ]*","",arbol$tip.label)
# check the TYPE numbers are correct
col_assignment = tol18rainbow[1:length(unique(TYPE))]
names( col_assignment) = unique(TYPE)
COLS = col_assignment[TYPE]
# then pass COLS into your plot
```

Comment: This looks exactly like what I want but could you maybe explain a bit on how you got the COLS variable? do you maybe have an idea how I could extract that from my example column?

Comment: Sure. your result from bionj (my case trw, your case arbol) will have a label. You just assign a color based on your logic / choice. In your case, try COLS = ifelse(grepl("celltype",arbol$tip.label),"blue","orange").

Comment: So close! but would it be possible to add multiple colors? So everything that has no celltype the same color --> something like ifelse(grepl("sample_",arbol$tip.label),"blue","orange") but then a different color for all unique celltypes? so cell1_sample13 and cell1_sample54 have the same color but cell2_sample14 has a differnt color. Sorry if I am being unclear!

Comment: 14 different types

Comment: I have edited my answer. In the future, provide a full csv file or txt of the matrix. Will be easier. I have to guess your dataset

Comment: I tried your sollution but it doesnt work .. I believe something could be wrong with the gsub because it colours 14 names in a different colour and the rest is in black .. and i added a link to my dataset thanks for the tip!

Comment: Cool. Can you make it publicly accessible?

Comment: It should be accessible now!

Comment: I fixed the problem! It should have been "TYPE = sub("\\_.*", "", arbol1$tip.label)" Still many thanks you are the best!!!!

Comment: Great! I just saw the bug too =p Typed too fast

Comment: @StupidWolf how to add external annotation to the tips label ? if I have to add some species information in form of groups how to do that?

Comment: change the $tip.label under bionj object? Not sure i understood your question